# How to print out multiple If Statement in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have been trying to display this if statement in my VB form application with no luck. Below is the code I have attempted.

```
 Dim iNumber1 As Double
    Dim iNumber2 As Double
    Dim iNumber3 As Double
    Dim iNumber4 As Double
    Dim iNumber5 As Double
    Dim iNumber6 As Double
    Dim iNumber7 As Double
    Dim iAns As Double
    Dim overall As Double

    iNumber1 = TextBox1.Text
    iNumber2 = TextBox2.Text
    iNumber3 = TextBox3.Text
    iNumber4 = TextBox7.Text
    iNumber5 = TextBox6.Text
    iNumber6 = TextBox5.Text
    iNumber7 = TextBox8.Text

    iAns = iNumber1 + iNumber2 + iNumber3 + iNumber4 + iNumber5 + iNumber6 + iNumber7
    overall = (Math.Round(Val(iAns / 7), 1))


    If iNumber1 <= 1.9 Then
        TextBox4.Text = $"Comprehension: {iNumber1} Entering"
    ElseIf iNumber1 >= 2.9 And iNumber1 >= 2 Then
        TextBox4.Text = $"Comprehension: {iNumber1} Emerging"
    ElseIf iNumber1 >= 3.9 And iNumber1 >= 3 Then
        TextBox4.Text = $"Comprehension: {iNumber1} Developing"
    ElseIf iNumber1 >= 4.9 And iNumber1 >= 4 Then
        TextBox4.Text = $"Comprehension: {iNumber1} Expanding"
    ElseIf iNumber1 >= 5.9 And iNumber1 >= 5 Then
        TextBox4.Text = $"Comprehension: {iNumber1} Bridging"
    ElseIf iNumber1 >= 6.9 And iNumber1 >= 6 Then
        TextBox4.Text = $"Comprehension: {iNumber1} Reaching"
    End If
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to come out? I am totally stuck. Thanks.

Comment: *display this if statement in my VB form application with no luck* - what does that mean?

Comment: Use the `round` functions, You are comparing potentially different numbers. `If iNumber1 <= 1.9 Then` did you print it out. It could be `1.89999999999999999999999999999`.

Comment: This iNumber1 >= 2.9 And iNumber1 >= 2 Then will always be True if the first comparison is True. Are you perhaps trying to get the values in between? 2 - 2.9, 3 - 3.9, etc? Then it should be If iNumber1 >= 2 And iNumber1 <= 2.9 Then...

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b most likely has the solution to your problem, that is you're using the wrong comparison operators. That said, in **cases** _(see what I did there?)_ like this, the [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) statement is a cleaner/better fit than mutliple `ElseIf` statements.